# SQL: CONSTRAINT [myPK] PRIMARY KEY [nothing specified here] CLUSTERED

Tags: sql, sql-server, key, constraints

I have this code (in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2017):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEStau](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What they actually meant to achieve here, was a PRIMARY KEY on the Id-field (and only on Id).

But is this what happens here? Because no field names are specified, something like this:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY (Id) CLUSTERED
```

Will then, by default, all columns be involved in this PRIMARY KEY?

So my question:

Has this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEStau](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the same effect as this piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEStau](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thanks already for your helpful answer!

Comment: "What happens if", why not try and see?

Comment: What happens at the moment is that this system is very slow. I am not an expert, so I am wondering what this code actually does. I can not change code like that, but I am only investigation this....

Comment: On my database system, if I change it as indicated, I get an error. If it's valid syntax for yours, it may be dialect specific so please add an appropriate tag to indicate what RDBMS product you're working with. It's also a *really good idea* to set up a local instance of that product on your own machine so that you can e.g. create new databases, tables, views with impunity and *experiment*. You'll learn a lot more by *doing*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query, you *do* have a field list specified, namely

```
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

ASC means that the rows are stored in ascending order, which is also the default.

The following code doesn't work because you will get a syntax error (missing column list):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEStau](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

... , but

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEStau](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

... Creates *almost* the same key as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEStau](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
)
```

The only difference is that with `CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` you specify the name of the key. With `[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key` the name of your key will get some kind of identifier, like `PK__tblEStau__3214EC0769EA2D7C`.

Comment: You typed that in that first case I would get a syntax-error... But: NO! So, that is where my question did come from. 

So:
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  compiles,
and:
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEStau] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
gives me an error....

Comment: In the very first query, you do have a column list specified (`([ID] ASC)`), so that one works. The second one, after "Has this...", gives an error. https://i.imgur.com/YFUCfJt.png . If you add `(ID)` after `primary key clustered` it works as well.

Comment: Okay, I got it! I did not pay attention much to: ([Id] ASC), but this statement is actually there, only poor formatted!

Comment: Yes, I know the "script table as..." option creates the script like that, but I have no idea why this has to be on the next line. I agree it's not directly obvious that it belongs to the definition of the PK.